# Django-registration - Register form returns gaierror[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: django, email, django-registration

**This is my settings.py for email settings:**

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'K132465789'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**This is the error generated if I try to register:**

```
gaierror at /register/

[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.18.39/register/
Django Version:     1.4.2
Exception Type:     gaierror
Exception Value:    

[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py in create_connection, line 553
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.2
Python Path:
```

I checked for similar issues on the web, but I couldn't find any solution, mostly there are only examples on how to set up settings.py, but they correspond to what I did. for example (http://ltslashgt.com/2007/07/02/gmail-and-django/)
I also checked the django-registration documentation but it doesn't say anything about possible issues. here (https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/v0.8/quickstart.html).

Comment: Were you able to address this error? I am getting exactly same error now. Please help if you could figure out something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm probably late to your problem, I'll leave this here for the people that gets here looking for a solution:

My problem is that I had broken the DNS configuration on my server, I changed the DNS servers to working ones and everything worked.